# How do I change mysql output based on value

Tags: mysql

For example, if queue_watch shows a 0, I want the actual mysql output to say No, else say Yes.  Changing the scheme is not an option.

```
SELECT user.user_name, queue.queue_name, queue_access.queue_access,
    queue_access.queue_watch
FROM queue_access
INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = queue_access.user_id
INNER JOIN queue ON queue.queue_id = queue_access.queue_id
WHERE queue_access <> '' OR queue_watch = 1
ORDER BY user_name;
```

The SQL works for what I need, but I like to know if changing the output using SQL rather than PHP is possible.  Also, is it possible to group all the queue_names in one row to each user_name so I don't have to have 153 rows returned.

Thanks

Comment: "Also, is it possible to group..." Please look up `GROUP BY` in the manual. You may also want to look at `GROUP_CONCAT`. And please don't ask two completely unrelated questions in one question.

Comment: I know sorry for hijacking the two part question but since it was related to the same query I thought might as well.  I did think of GROUP BY but the problem is group by returns one user and one queue name, since one user can belong to many queues - so want it in a kind of list, but don't know if its possible

Comment: sorry i figured it out, group by on the bottom, with group_concat in the select did it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It not an over head. It is better to be done in the query, I feel.

Try this -

```
SELECT user.user_name, queue.queue_name, queue_access.queue_access,
       IF(queue_access.queue_watch = 0, 'No', 'Yes')
FROM queue_access
INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = queue_access.user_id
INNER JOIN queue ON queue.queue_id = queue_access.queue_id
WHERE queue_access <> '' OR queue_watch = 1
ORDER BY user_name;
```

Comment: This one actually solved what I needed, (I saw it first honestly), and I just added the as to rename the column.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the standard `CASE` expression. There are two slightly different ways to write a `CASE` expression.

Simple case expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE queue_access.queue_watch
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS your_alias,
    ...
```

Searched case expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN queue_access.queue_watch = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS your_alias,
    ...
```

Or you could use the MySQL specific [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) construct:

```
SELECT
    IF(queue_access.queue_watch, 'Yes', 'No') AS your_alias,
    ...
```

You may want to consider what should happen if your value is something other than 0 or 1.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Sorry I was actually going to add that. I was just was testing my answer in SQL Fiddle just to make sure everything was OK, but to my surprise it didn't work there. Wasn't sure if I had mis-remembered the syntax, mistyped something, or if there was a bug in SQL Fiddle. Seems like it's a [bug in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/711).

Comment: Nice job showing the ANSI standard way with `CASE` as well as more succinct MySQL `IF` method.

Comment: I like the case..as method, but where do I put the case, I get sql error no matter where i plop it into the query.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub: Erm, maybe it was the missing `END` keyword. Edited answer. Try refreshing the page.

Comment: @MarkByers The bug is due to the column name having a comma in it.  Adding a alias (sans-comma) works around it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/775

Comment: @MarkByers I've fixed this bug, now.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/711  Thanks!

Comment: @JakeFeasel: Thanks for fixing the bug, and for making a very excellent tool. :-)